# Instant run is disabled for the current variant

Tags: android, intellij-idea

*I have seen many questions like this, but they didn't solve my problem.*

I use IntelliJ IDEA for developing Android applications. Whenever I run an app and deploy it to a device, whether it is a physical device or an emulator, the instant run option always remains greyed out, even if the app is already running. When I hover over the icon, the cursor tip shows that `Instant run is disabled for the current variant`. See this :
[image]

In the IDE errors panel, it shows this :
[image]

I had already used this feature in Android Studio without any problems, but I can't find the solution to this problem in IntelliJ. Please help me solve this problem. I am using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA.